# Do transients speed up read operations?

Tags: optimization, clojure

In my application, I have a huge nested map of immutable state that I query very often with operations such-as `get-in`.

Whenever performing a lot of read operations on such structure, do I get any benefit from converting it into a transient? Or do transients only speed-up update operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For built-in transient-enabled Clojure data structures (and any data structures implemented using the same general strategy), **there is no read-related benefit to using transients**. In fact, transients need to perform a little extra work for lookups –  a single `.get` on an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) and a branch on the result. Normally this will barely be measurable, so it's not something to worry about when using transients where their key value proposition (faster chains of updates) is relevant, but at any rate it does mean that they won't make lookups any faster.

This is because transients use almost the same internal structures as their persistent counterparts<sup>1</sup> (indeed after a `persistent!` call, the transient's internal tree is used directly in the newly created persistent data structure), so their lookup logic is very nearly the same, but as a matter of transients' general API contract, any attempted lookups after a `persistent!` call on a given transient must result in an `IllegalAccessError`. This costs transients a tiny amount of extra effort each time one attempts a lookup.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some minor differences: e.g. transient vectors always use a 32-element array as a tail (paired with a field tracking the current "end index"), whereas persistent vectors use an array of as many items as the tail actually holds; this means that growing a tail can be accomplished with in-place mutation most of the time (in a chain of `conj!`s, only 1 in 32 needs to allocate a new tail array), and it causes no issues for the persistent version, as when you call `persistent!` the tail is trimmed again. This doesn't really affect the present discussion, though.

<sup>2</sup> As a matter of fact, the same tiny cost is paid for writes as well, but there the benefits of often being able to update the data structure in place rather instead of allocating new nodes easily outweigh it.

Answer (score 3):

Transients are designed to speed up **writes** by batching updates. Their purpose is not to optimize reads and if that is your goal, I would not use them (using a more efficient data structure for lookup is likely to be a better answer).

**Reads** on a transient data structure can be either slower or faster because they need to check both the data structure and the in-process batch. If the value happens to be in the just-added batch, reads *might* be faster. If they happen to be in the larger data structure, they might be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on transient structures says that you will get O(1) performance for creation of the structure itself (therefore calling `transient`). Update operations is faster than normal ones (like `assoc`) however I would expect reading to be the same. You can find more detailed explanation in the Clojure [reference](https://clojure.org/reference/transients).